# c#, mysql connection string for multiple subnets

Tags: c#, mysql, connection-string, subnet

I have a desktop application on Winforms, the application works locally on Wampserver, adds and retrieves data from the Mysql database, the connection string looks like this

```
 MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection("server = 192.130.1.1; UserId = admin; Password = 12345; database = employee");
```

the application works in this subnet, and so I need the application to work in such subnets, 192.130.30.1; 192.130.5.1 how to do it, no idea..please, help me!

Comment: You should probably just use a DNS name and have that DNS name update dynamically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

fixed, it turns out to be very simple

```
 MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection("server = 192.130.1.1,192.168.1.199,192.1 ; UserId = admin; Password = 12345; database = employee");
```

Comment: does it really work for you?